# Type declared in companion object not found by Scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

In Scala macro (2.11|2.12), I don't find a way to support types (case classes or case object) declared in a companion object.

By example for the following types ...

```
sealed trait Foo

object Foo {
  case class Bar(lorem: String) extends Foo
  case object Ipsum extends Foo
}
```

... with a macro declared as bellow ...

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

def testImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._

  val tpe = c.weakTypeOf[A]

  c.typecheck(q"""$tpe.unapply(Foo.Bar("lorem"))""")

  reify({})
}

def test[A] = macro testImpl[A]
```

..., when calling it for the type `Foo.Bar` with `test[Foo.Bar]`, the compile error is raised:

```
error: exception during macro expansion:
scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: value unapply is not a member of Foo.Bar
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$3(Typers.scala:32)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$2(Typers.scala:26)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.doTypecheck$1(Typers.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.$anonfun$typecheck$7(Typers.scala:38)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$Lambda$676/541572263.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm(Trees.scala:1710)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.wrappingIntoTerm$(Trees.scala:1707)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.wrappingIntoTerm(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck(Typers.scala:38)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers.typecheck$(Typers.scala:20)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
    at .testImpl(<pastie>:31)

       test[Foo.Bar]
           ^
```

Testing directly with `c.typecheck(q"""Foo.Bar.unapply(Foo.Bar("lorem"))""")` there is not error, so I guess there is something more to do about the type resolution.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors when I write `${tpe.companion}` instead of just `$tpe`, but I don't know what your goal is with it, so it could very well not help.

Comment: Have already tried it, in my case it's not sufficient but seems to somehow work if used with `.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.returnType` (with return the fully qualified type)

Comment: It seems like unquoting a type where you need a term is going to be fragile at best. It's unclear from the question what will be a sufficient answer.